# Missing argument 1 for JobController::seejobseach()

Tags: php, function, laravel

"Missing argument 1 for JobController::seejobseach()"
I honestly dont know what to do

JobController.php -

```
public function seejobseach($id)
{
    $job = Job::find($id);
    return View::make('job.seeJobsEach')->with('job', $job);
}
```

seeJobsEach.blade.php -

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
<h1>Jobs</h1>
<p>Name: {{{ $job->title }}}</p>
<p>Description: {{{ $job->description }}}</p>
@stop
```

Comment: You're missing an argument (variable) for `seejobsearch()`. It even told you so.

Comment: We honestly don't know either: post your routes and how you build your link --> likely you forgot to put the job id there

Comment: It seems that you have missed to pass the id to the function.Please share the url and route for better understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `seejobseach` method accepts one parameter as `$id`

```
public function seejobseach($id)
{
    // ...
}
```

But you are not providing it when you are accessing via `route`. For example, if you are using an `URI`like this:

```
http://domain/jobsearch
```

Then you should pass the `id` using something like this:

```
http://domain/jobsearch/10
```

Because your route probably looks something like this:

```
Route::get('jobsearch', 'JobController@seejobseach');
```

But it should be like this:

```
Route::get('jobsearch/{id}', 'JobController@seejobseach');
```

So the `id` you pass in your `URI` would be passed to the `seejobseach` method as it's parameter and if you use something like this:

```
http://domain/jobsearch/10
```

Then `10` would be passed into the `seejobseach` method in the `$id` variable.